# I compiled a c lua extension dll in lua5.1 on windows, and it functions well in lua command line mode, but can not use it in openresty

Tags: dll, lua, openresty

There is a c code called lua-pack.c, provided [here](https://github.com/Kong/lua-pack/), which is a lua extension for process hex string, I need to use it in openresty to process some network stream.

I install it in windows with lua5.1 and luarocks

I successfully get the lua-pack.dll. All the test ran successfully in command line mode like this

> lua C:\projects\lua-pack\lua-pack\test.lua

But once I put this lua-pack.dll in openresty's dir, and use it, some exception will throw like

```
worker process 24892 exited with code C0000005
```

I can successfully compile lua-pack.so (compile by makefile) in ubuntu and  it functions right in openresty in linux. I tried to copy this lua-pack.so to windows, and it throws exception says this so is not for windows use.

However, I noticed that in test.lua provided [here](https://github.com/Kong/lua-pack/blob/master/test.lua) by the author  it require(pack) instead of require(lua_pack)

So I renamed the lua-pack.dll to pack.dll, then I got another exception

```
lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: error loading module 'pack' from file '.\pack.dll':
```

I do notice that this is a pack.lua in lua-rocks windows, I don't know whether this matters.

test.lua provided by the author start like this, this can be run in Windows command line

```
require"pack"
bpack=string.pack
bunpack=string.unpack
```

My code works in Linux openresty start like this

```
local bpack, bunpack
do
    local string_pack = string.pack
    local string_unpack = string.unpack
    require "lua_pack"
    bpack = string.pack
    bunpack = string.unpack
    -- luacheck: globals string.unpack
    string.unpack = string_unpack
    -- luacheck: globals string.pack
    string.pack = string_pack
end
```

Comment: You state you have the code working. What is the question? Unfortunately different naming conventions is something you have to live with. If you want portability you can do an OS check before 'require'. However, lua51 doesn't have native capability to do this.

Comment: Code just works in linux openresty , doesn't work under windows openresty, however it works in windows lua command line, that's the problem